# BR tag being moved outside SPAN after rendering or editor.getData()

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, django-ckeditor, ckeditor.net

I'm using ckeditor 4.9 after editing when rendering/refresh the editor it is moving the `'<br>'` tag.

Actual Code:

```
"<p><span style="font-size: 22px;"><b>This is&nbsp;Heading<br><br></b></span><br>sd<br>f<br>sdf<br>sd<br>fsfds s sd f sd f sdf</p>"
```

result: editor.getData();

```
"<p><span style="font-size: 22px;"><b>This is&nbsp;Heading</b></span><br />
<br />
<br />
sd<br />
f<br />
sdf<br />
sd<br />
fsfds s sd f sd f sdf</p>
```

Comment: I quickly created a jsfilddle for this, if you could add the options you are using already, so we can figure out why this is happening https://jsfiddle.net/03qgbu59/

Comment: check this: https://jsfiddle.net/Wsmemon/8uc5xk3f/ there is jumping issue after rendering. @tasaduq